# (Swift + Spritekit) - remove node and its data entirely

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm working a little game for iOS.

I've a SKSpriteNode in my scene - when I remove it with "removeFromParent" and touch the area it was last in, I still get the function.

My code is as following:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if tapToPlayNode.containsPoint(location){
            tapToPlayNode.removeFromParent()
            startNewGame()
        }
    }
}

func startNewGame(){
    //Starts a new game with resetted values and characters in position
    println("Ready.. set.. GO!")

    //Shows the ui (value 1)
    toggleUiWithValue(1)
}
```

In other words, I get "Ready.. set.. GO!" output when I touch the area even after it was deleted.

Any clues?

Bests,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `tapToPlayNode` is still retained by self and is removed from it's parent.
You should make it optional `var tapToPlayNode:SKSpriteNode?`and nil it after remove it from it's parent like this:

```
if let playNode = self.tapToPlayNode {
   for touch: AnyObject in touches {
   let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if playNode.containsPoint(location) {
            playNode.removeFromParent()
            startNewGame()
            self.tapToPlayNode = nil // il it here!
            break
        }
    }
}
```

You can also avoid to keep a reference of your tapToPlayNode and give it a name when initializing it like this:

```
node.name = @"tapToPlayNodeName"
// Add node to scene and do not keep a var to hold it!

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
/* Called when a touch begins */

    // Retrieve the ode here
    let tapToPlayNode = container.childNodeWithName("tapToPlayNodeName")!
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
       let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if tapToPlayNode.containsPoint(location){
            tapToPlayNode.removeFromParent()
            startNewGame()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you many times for your swift answer, Bsarr! One quickie though: when I use the "var tapToPlayNode:SKSpriteNode?" I cannot texture the node, it seems?

Comment: @bsarr007 Do you have to nil the SKSpriteNode after restarting the new game or does it still work after removing it from the parent before starting a new game? Currently I need to wipe a list of optional SKSpriteNodes, but it doesn't seem to be working by setting them to nil after they are removed from the parent. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Treutlein, i don't know exactly your problem but in the second example i gave, you don't have to nil nothing, the SpriteKitNode `"tapToPlayNodeName"` is just referenced by name, there is no variable that hold it, after remove it from it's parent it's no more referenced.